# WIX extracting Binary table data to TempFolder

Tags: binary, wix, custom-action

During install I need to extract a text file from Binary data and place it in TempFolder so it can be used by a dll I don't control. It needs to be passed the file-name of the text for processing.

I thought I could use a simple custom action to invoke xcopy to copy the data but how do I identify the contents of the binary table?

Secondly, customaction supports various actions but I don't see anything obvious to just drop the binary item into the TempFolder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built in to MSI or WiX to do that. You can just install the file normally and reference its path using [#fileId] formatted syntax.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need this "file" for a dll that runs in an install customaction. so it can't be "installed"

Comment: It can, as long as the custom action is deferred and runs after the InstallFiles standard action.

Comment: It can't. It's a custom EULA dialog that needs to run early in the install process.

could I do something to access the msi database from within a custom action, extract the binary content and do my own write? This would be new territory for me, but what the heck, why not. just point me to an example.

Comment: Yes, custom actions can access the database. You can query for the data stream using a SQL query like "SELECT `Data` FROM `Binary` WHERE `Name`='whatever'".